# SQL: Use REGEXP_REPLACE on query parameter inside of LIKE statement

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a query which is supposed to find matching rows ignoring case and special characters that may be present both in the query and the corresponding column. For that I use `REGEXP_REPLACE` like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Order
WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(reference, '[^a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]', '') LIKE %:search%
```

where `search` is the name of the parameter I want to use. That works, but doesn't yet sanitize the `search` parameter from unwanted special characters.

What I would like to do is something like the following, i.e. having the `REGEXP_REPLACE` on the right side as well:

```
SELECT *
FROM Order
WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(reference, '[^a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]', '') LIKE %REGEXP_REPLACE(:search, '[^a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]', '')%
```

However that doesn't work and I get the following error:

```
42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%REGEXP_REPLACE(
```

Is it not possible to use a function on the parameter or as part of a `LIKE` statement? Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to create a string starting and ending with '%' to use in your LIKE operator. To do that in MySQL's dialect of SQL you need to do your string manipulation explicitly using the built-in string manipulation functions.

You can use those functions anywhere your query needs a text string.

Try using [CONCAT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/concat/) in an expression like this to generate that string. You'll be able to use it on the right side of your LIKE.

```
CONCAT('%', REGEXP_REPLACE(:search, '[^a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]', ''), '%')
```

I hope you don't want your query to be fast.  It will be slow. It must examine every value of `Order.reference` in your table.  It's slow because

1. it's not [sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable) due to `WHERE f(column) LIKE whatever`, and
2. `column LIKE '%something%'` requires looking at every value of `column`, rather than random-acccessing a [BTREE index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-btree-hash.html#btree-index-characteristics).

If you build a database to scale up, you design it so your queries can be sargeable. Sargability here might look like

```
WHERE cleaned_up_reference 
 LIKE CONCAT(REGEXP_REPLACE(:search, '[^a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]', ''), '%')
```

*without* the leading `%` on the right, and without evaluating any function on the column or columns being searched.

Comment: This works, thank you!
If I understand correctly, using a function after the `LIKE` wasn't the problem, but rather that the syntax wasn't correctly, i.e. a String was expected and I didn't provided. Using `CONCAT` makes it a String and therefore it works!?

As this is a search it would be good if it was fast... I am aware that this is not an optimal solution yet and may require extending/improving the database schema (or using something like elasticsearch...)

Comment: Exactly. PLease see my edit

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Order a
WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(a.reference, '[^a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]', '') LIKE '%:search%'
```

Comment: This works, but doesn't solve what I was struggling with. The same regex is supposed to be applied to `:search` (i.e. the right hand side after `LIKE`), too.